# How can I show my Images from Firebase Storage to my website?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="file" id="dosya" @change="putDesign()" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, listAll } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fileName: "",
      resim: "",
      photos: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
  mounted() {
    // Create a reference under which you want to list
    const listRef = ref(storage, "design/");

    // Find all the prefixes and items.
    listAll(listRef)
      .then((res) => {
        res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
          // All the prefixes under listRef.
          // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
          console.log(folderRef);
        });
        res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
          // All the items under listRef.
          this.photos.push(itemRef+ " ");
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

I can add files to my Firebase Storage, but I cannot show them on my website. I can get Local Storage Location but I cannot get Access Token, so I cannot open or show photos. Is there a way to get the Access Token? I searched on Firebase Documentation, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get the `downloadURL` for each element in the folder. It could look like this:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, listAll, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fileName: "",
      resim: "",
      photos: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
  mounted() {
    // Create a reference under which you want to list
    const listRef = ref(storage, "design/");

    // Find all the prefixes and items.
    listAll(listRef)
      .then((res) => {
        res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
          // All the prefixes under listRef.
          // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
          console.log(folderRef);
        });
        res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
          // All the items under listRef.
          getDownloadURL(itemRef).then(downloadURL=>{
              this.photos.push(downloadURL);
          })
          
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
};
```